# VB.NET simulate button click and how do I return it to normal?

Tags: vb.net, button, keycode, simulate

I have difficulty with this code, I explain:
I have created a textbox and when I press enter, it simulates clicking on a button.

```
Sub TextBox1KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        'simulate to press Button
        Button1Click(sender,New EventArgs)
    Else
        'code to return to normal
    End If
End Sub
```

It works fine, **but how do I return it to normal?** I mean, when I click the button, it does not react.
Please wait for your help with this problem that arises

Comment: Do you subscribed eventhandler to click event. `AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button1Click` or having `Handles Button1.Click` when you declare `Button1Click` method?

Comment: hi, I do not understand your question, the truth is that I have not added what you say. Where do I place the handler event, on the original button or, where am I calling?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually not a good idea to call an event procedure. Move your code from the Button1.Click to a separate sub then call it from both places.

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown_1(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            'simulate to press Button
            MyButtonSub()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MyButtonSub()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyButtonSub()
        MessageBox.Show("Button One was clicked or pretend clicked.")
    End Sub
```

Comment: in Private Sub MyButtonSub() ---> paste code?, of the original button?

Comment: Yes. Then MyButtonSub() is called both by the buttton and the key down in the text box.

Comment: when placing Handles textBox1.KeyDown, get the following error, The Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the container type or one of its base types. (BC30506),Do you know why?

Comment: What is the name of your text box?

Comment: the name is textBox1

Comment: When you added the text box to your form did you rename it textBox1 because the default name would be TextBox1. When controls are added to the form at design time they are automatically added with events.

Comment: Excuse my mischief, I had changed its name, I am currently in Sharpdevelop and it is very limited, change of name?

Comment: Sorry, I am not at all familiar with Sharpdevelop. I use Visual Studio 2017 Community. It is free for the download and the license for individual developers is quite generous.

Comment: ok, ok, excuse me asking too much, the idea you've transmitted is fine, now I have to research the software, do not worry and thank you very much for your help.